# Use linq to get parent objects based on one of the property in a self referencing table

Tags: asp.net, sql, linq-to-sql

I have a table called Quiz that have these fields

```
id As Int
created As DateTime
header As Sring
body As String
fk_parent As int
url As String
```

All the items without parent key would be the question, and ones that have the parent key would be the answer. I am having the problem to get all the latest active questions (based both on questions created time and and answer created time).

I am struggling to write a Linq query that can do the above task.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a start:

```
IQueryable<int> keys =
    from x in dc.Quiz
    let masterID = ParentId.HasValue ? ParentId.Value : Id
    group x by masterID into g
    order g by g.Max(x => x.created) descending
    select g.Key

List<Quiz> = dc.Quiz.Where(x => keys.Take(20).Contains(x.Id)).ToList();
```

This assumes answers aren't parents of answers...  If they can - you have an arbitrary depth tree walk on your hands, which is a wrong shaped nail for Linq and for SQL.

Comment: I think this is the right approach, and I tried to combine the two command into one like this:
from x in dc.Quiz
    let masterID = ParentId.HasValue ? ParentId.Value : Id
    group x by masterID into g
    order g by g.Max(x => x.created) descending
    select (new {masterItem}=from x in g where x.parentid =null}

The problem is that, I have the return values with answer and questions in seperate groups, the answer of a question is not in the same group as the question. I know it is nearly the, digging it .

Answer (score 0):

You could try joining the table on itself in LINQ and creating a new object that holds the Questions and answers:

```
var QandA = from q in tbl
        join a in tbl on q.id equals a.fk_parent
        select new {
        QHeader = q.header,
        QBody = q.body,
        QUrl = q.url,
        AHeader = a.header,
        ABody = a.body,
        AUrl = a.url
        };
```

I think this is how your table is setup, but I might have the join wrong.